# How to decrypt Encrypted text to plaintext?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, base64, brute-force

I have an assignment on reverse engineering for cryptography and network security to decrypt API response. 
Is there are any solution to find the actual result of given text below.
I have used **Brute Force algorithm** for decryption of finding the decryption key for AES or DES algorithm but still i didn't got the solution. But i got an anonymous mail who tells me that he has all solution given response. How he get the decryption of given text.

```
Encrypted Text = p1SvSCiAxupKrrZXzjXQk48EeA7F1jnGymvqGlmAOMOrnUVZpopohJ8WYp/DI3nUuc4wG57FQWi2
TfwS+H7VSsanfbhKGf+i6H1iQchaSi9lgjxv96JCyhM9WaF7T9UuL5efwgwslGqGG54Ctx6Ykg==

Decrypted text=
{
  "status": {
    "status": "500",
    "message": "Your request could not be served by the system. Please try again!"
  }
}
```

Comment: finding decryption technique if we know plaintext and encrypted text are given

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/if-i-have-the-unencrypted-text-and-the-encrypted-text-can-i-calculate-the-key

Comment: it should be impossible. The only way to do that is brootforce (trying every possible key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the encryption method is an accepted standard method such as AES and the key is good it is not possible to find the key given the plain and encrypted data.

If the encryption method is trivial such as Caeser Cipher then it can be found.

If the key is trivial such as "password" or others found in lists of frequently used passwords it can be found with a brute force search.